# How many null directions are there?

Tags: spacetime, vectors, event-horizon, spacetime-dimensions

1. The metric signature of [spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime) is usually given as ($3,1$), but spaces can also be ($3,n,1$). [Null surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypersurface) include photons and [event horizons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon), which exist, so is $n$ actually $ > 1$ in the signature?
2. In theory, could an experiment establish the number of null dimensions/directions?
3. In another answer, someone said there are an infinite number of null directions. If that's true, is there ever any reason to specify $n$ in the [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_signature)?
4. Is there an example in physics where $n$ is explicitly presented as nonzero?

Comment: If this is a stupid question, please let someone answer it before deleting it as I have wanted to know this ever since reading about metric signatures as a kid.

Comment: *spaces can also be (3,n,1)* What source specifies a signature as $(3,n,1)$?

Comment: *let someone answer it before deleting it* I don’t think questions with upvoted answers get deleted, even if the question has downvotes.

Comment: (3,n,1)? This is the definition of metric signature. Eigenvalues can be zero in the metric tensor. The basis vectors can be zero. This is fascinatins, and I want to understand the physical significance, if any, of the null basis. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MetricSignature.html

Comment: That article says “its signature is defined to be the ordered pair $(p,q)$ where $p$, respectively $q$, denotes the number positive, respectively negative, terms in the expansion of $ds^2$”. It doesn’t mention a signature like $(3,n,1)$, so why did you offer that article?

Comment: *Eigenvalues can be zero in the metric tensor.* This is false.

Comment: *The basis vectors can be zero.* This is false. They can be *null*, which is completely different.

Comment: Wolfram defines the signature (v, p, r) as the number of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues. I want to know the significance of p.

Comment: In which paragraph? Wherever it is, if it is anywhere, it isn’t relevant to the metric tensor. You are again in the realm of non-mainstream physics and personal theories.

Comment: As Andrew’s answer states, **there are no zero eigenvalues in the metric**.

Comment: Oops, I had a wikipedia tab open and I quoted that. See this  instead. https://dbpedia.org/page/Metric_signature

Comment: The middle (null) parameter is usually omitted by convention as an implied 0, but it exists. Ref on request. I'm not pushing a crazy "theory;" I just want to understand what's going on. Anyone will tell you that I never know what the hell is going on around me, and "what's around me" is the universe.

Comment: *I just want to understand what's going on.* Here is what happens if you try to allow the metric tensor to have eigenvalues with value zero: You can’t define the inverse metric. You can’t define the Christoffel symbols. You can’t define the Riemann tensor. You can’t define the Ricci tensor. You can’t define the Ricci scalar. You can’t formulate the Einstein field equations. The volume of spacetime is zero.

Comment: If you have understood Andrew’s answer, you now know that spacetime having null directions is not related to the metric tensor having zero eigenvalues.

Comment: In the physically-irrelevant $(v,p,r)$ notation — irrelevant because $r$ is always zero — the signature of spacetime is $(1,3,0)$, not $(3,0,1)$. You misunderstood the meaning of $v$, $p$, and $r$.

Comment: Yes, I marked Andrew's answer as "the" answer. I think that closes the question, or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: I don’t see anything more that you need to do.

Comment: A recent edit by someone else revealed that Wikipedia’s article “[Metric signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_signature)” includes the $(v,p,r)$ notation, without explaining why $r$ is always 0 for a spacetime metric, so I’ve reversed my downvote.

Comment: That article is problematic for me as a physicist. For example, it refers to time as a “virtual” dimension (hence the $v$ notation), which is not terminology that relativists use. It calls the spatial dimensions “physical” (hence the $p$ notation). The notion that space is “physical” but time isn’t is not shared by most physicists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The signature of the metric is determined by the *eigenvalues* of the metric. Using a convention where spacelike distances are positive and timelike distances are negative, the Minkowski metric (describing spacetime without gravity) has $3$ positive and $1$ negative eigenvalue. In standard coordinates, the metric looks like (in units where $c=1$)
$$
\eta_{\mu\nu} = \left(
\begin{matrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

The Minkowski metric *does* have null directions, but there are no zero eigenvalues in the metric. It is just that there are distances where the negative (timelike) contribution to the distance exactly cancel the positive (spacelike) contribution to the distance.

For example, if $\Delta x = (A, A, 0, 0)$, then
$$
\eta_{\mu\nu} \Delta x^\mu \Delta x^\nu = -A + A = 0
$$

There are, as you said, an infinite number of null directions, but this isn't that surprising -- light can travel in an infinite number of directions. However, the existence of null directions is not relevant for the signature of the metric. The signature is just (3, 1).

Comment: To put it more geometrically, there are lots of null vectors, but it's impossible to use one as an element of an orthogonal basis.

Comment: Thank you. I will conclude that the null term in the formal definition of signature exists only for mathematical completeness with no physical significance. I"ll mark this as answered.

Comment: @Miss_Understands For what it's worth I've never seen a null term in the definition of signature.

Comment: @andrew https://dbpedia.org/page/Metric_signature It is omitted by convention because it's usually ignored.

Comment: @Miss_Understands It is perhaps worth noting that there are some variation in the conventions used for the metric of Minkoski space in physics, for example one will also often see the metric tensor written as:$$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1\\\end{pmatrix}.$$ So that in this case the line element appears as $ds^2=cdt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2$

Comment: Null directions have very high physical significance: they are the space-time directions of photons.

Comment: @Miss_Understands Ah ok, but in that definition then the number of null (or zero) eigenvalues of the metric is zero, for Minkowski space (ie, for special relativity). It also is generally zero in general relativity, except (a) at horizons, which is an artifact of choosing "bad" coordinates, or (b) at singularities, where the geometry of the manifold becomes pathological.

Comment: @lee "Null directions have very high physical significance" I know! So do the negative ones, and I'm exploring both!

Comment: @albertus yes,ty.  multiply the the metric by the imaginary unit and flip the signature.

Comment: @andrew OBOY! I don't believe in singularities, but how are null dimensions involved in event horizons? is it because x --> 0 due to gravitational (relativistic) contraction?

Comment: @Miss_Understands It just turns out that in some coordinates, an eigenvalue of the metric becomes zero on the horizon in the [Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) describing a non-spinning black hole (and another becomes infinite). But it's possible to find [other coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates) where this does not happen.

Comment: @Andy which eigenvalue goes infinite? It probably has to with gravity, right?

Comment: @Miss_Understands It might be better to ask a different question about the conditions under which the metric signature can change since this topic is too complicated for a comment section. The example I gave does involve gravity -- it's the metric for a non-spinning black hole. However, you can also find coordinates in flat spacetime (with no gravity) with an apparent horizon -- [Rindler coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates) (describing uniformly accelerating observers in special relativity).

Comment: @andy looking at the metric, it looks like all 4 dimensions shrink to 0, because they're all multiplied by how close you are to the horizon. I guess that explains why time doesn't pass.

Comment: @andy -- rindler coords, ty. I reeeally hesitate to ask questions, but another rabbit hole to explore on my own!  comments closed.